# Как перенести информацию массива в следующий элемент tr

Tags: javascript

Возникла такая проблема.

Как перенести информацию массива в следующий tr, если в одной tr может содержаться только четыре td.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cell = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
  var tableContainer = document.querySelector("table");
  var tbodyContainer = tableContainer.querySelector("tbody");
  cell.forEach(function(Onecell) {
    if (Onecell === 0) {
      var dead = document.createElement("tr");
      tbodyContainer.appendChild(dead);
      var cellCreate = document.createElement("td");
      // добавляем только что созданый элемент в дерево DOM
      cellCreate.classList.add("dead");
      dead.appendChild(cellCreate);
    } else {
      var live = document.createElement("tr");
      tbodyContainer.appendChild(live);
      var cellCreate = document.createElement("td");
      // добавляем только что созданый элемент в дерево DOM
      cellCreate.classList.add("live");
      live.appendChild(cellCreate);
    }
  });

}
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
.dead {
  background-color: red;
}
.live {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvb4c3a0/1/

Comment: Обернуть в цикл for с 4-мя итерациями, был бы код на jsfiddle дописал бы

Comment: _tbodyContainer.querySelector("tr")_ - возвращает первую строку, поэтому и добавляется все в одну. выбирай/создавай другие строки в зависимости от индекса ячейки и все

Comment: добавь пример разметки к которой применяется данный код

Comment: Добавил html, код js немного поменял.

Comment: Нормального ответа так и не получил.

Comment: а ничего, что в последней строке вместо 4 ячеек будет 2? какая-то не совсем правильная таблица получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал немного и оптимизировал https://jsfiddle.net/zvb4c3a0/5/

```
var cell = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1];
var tableContainer = document.querySelector("table");
var tbodyContainer = tableContainer.querySelector("tbody");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var counter = 0;

cell.forEach(function(Onecell) {

  //% - это остаток от деления
  if(counter%4 == false) {
    tbodyContainer.appendChild(tr);
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
  }

  var cell = document.createElement("td");
  // добавляем только что созданый элемент в дерево DOM
  cell.classList.add(Onecell == 0 ? "dead" : "live");
  tr.appendChild(cell);
  counter++;

});
```

Comment: Круто! Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, стоит определиться с исходными данными. Сейчас это плоский массив, поэтому не ясно где происходит деление на строки.

Если его предварительно обработать и получить двумерный массив, то вложенные массивы будут непосредственно строками и сразу станет понятно какие данные отображаются на какую строку.

Например, для текущего массива можно получить следующий двумерный

```
[
    [0, 1, 1, 0], 
    [1, 0, 1, 0], 
    [1, 0, 1, 1], 
    [0, 1, 1, 1], 
    [0, 1]
];
```

Получить такой вид можно используя [функцию reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
var maxCountInRow = 4;
var processedCells = cells.reduce(function(acc,el,index){
    var rowIndex = Math.floor(index/maxCountInRow);
    acc[rowIndex] = acc[rowIndex] || [];
    acc[rowIndex].push(el); 
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Теперь данный массив легко спроецировать на список строк с ячейками

```
processedCells.reduce(function(tbody, cells){
    tbody.appendChild(// добавляем создаваемую строку
        cells.reduce(function(tr, el){ // создаем ячейки
            var td = document.createElement('td');
            td.classList.add(el==0?'dead':'live');
            tr.appendChild(td);
            return tr;
        }, document.createElement('tr')/*создаем строку*/);
    );
    return tbody;
}, tbodyContainer);
```

Если все собрать, получится следующее:

```js
var cell = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
var tableContainer = document.querySelector("table");
var tbodyContainer = tableContainer.querySelector("tbody");

var maxCountInRow = 4;
var processedCells = cell.reduce(function(acc, el, index) {
  var rowIndex = Math.floor(index / maxCountInRow);
  acc[rowIndex] = acc[rowIndex] || [];
  acc[rowIndex].push(el);
  return acc;
}, []);

processedCells.reduce(function(tbody, cells) {
  tbody.appendChild( // добавляем создаваемую строку
    cells.reduce(function(tr, el) { // создаем ячейки
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.classList.add(el == 0 ? 'dead' : 'live');
      tr.appendChild(td);
      return tr;
    }, document.createElement('tr') /*создаем строку*/ )
  );
  return tbody;
}, tbodyContainer);
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
.dead {
  background-color: red;
}
.live {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Как можно заметить, подряд выполняются две свертки над одними данными, и их можно объединить:

```js
var cell = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
var tableContainer = document.querySelector("table");
var tbodyContainer = tableContainer.querySelector("tbody");

var maxCountInRow = 4;
cell.reduce(function(tbody, cell, index) {
  if (index % maxCountInRow == 0) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  } else {
    var tr = tbody.querySelector('tr:last-child');
  }
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.classList.add(cell == 0 ? 'dead' : 'live');
  tr.appendChild(td);
  return tbody;
}, tbodyContainer);
```

```css
td {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
.dead {
  background-color: red;
}
.live {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```